# Algorithm for optimizing placement of unequal circles in a given rectangular area

Tags: geometry, optimization, circles, packing-problem

I am working on a project, in which I have to optimize the placement of **N unequal circles** in a given rectangular area, such that if these circles are considered as a sensor field, I can possibly reduce the points from where intrusions are possible.

The total area of N unequal circles is not fixed with respect to the given rectangle, i.e. combined area of circles can be less or approximately equal to the area of the rectangle.

So, basically I have to create a particular **optimised** configuration where there are minimal voids and intrusions.
I need an algorithm to implement this, such that I get relative coordinates of circles in such an optimal configuration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to maximize the area covered. However the following is an approximation. Put a grid of points on top of the rectangle. Then maximize the number of points covered by at least one sensor. Assume we have given set of sensors each with a given radius. Then we can formulate a Mixed Integer Quadratically Constrained Programming (MIQCP) problem  as follows:

[image]

Solvers like [Cplex](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/commerce/optimization/cplex-optimizer/) and [Gurobi](http://www.gurobi.com/) handle these type of problems. The results for some invented small data can look like:

[image]